# How can I use darknet library?

Tags: yolo, darknet

I want to use Darknet library in Python.
I've installed Darknet repository using this command.

git clone https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.git

But when I type ****import darknet as dn****
it says No module named darknet.

How can I install darknet module??
Is it possible using pip???

Answer (score 1):

Check this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pYh1rFnNZs&t=408s
and the second part of it. Use those steps and then try creating a python file in which you import darknet. Make sure that the python file from where you import darknet is in the same folder as darknet.py, otherwise you need to specify the path to the darknet.py in your import statement.(ex import f1.f2.f3.darknet)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'll refer to that url :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming across this question, note that the AlexeyAB repo was abandoned long ago.  The new repo, which has a new Python module, can be found here:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet#table-of-contents

The Python module and example source code can be found in src-python.